# how to retrieve all nested class name in list<WebElement> of Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: HTML Code]

How to retrieve all nested classes of parent class ?

I wants to get name of class (toast toast-success & toast-message). I can have stable id=toast-container but its nested class can be change. so need to retrieve all classes of toast-container.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB
Thanks for notifying. But this HTML code presence for 1 second only and can not copy it within that duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using xpath. There are several ways to do this, here are two examples. I use C#, but that doesn't change the xpaths. My camel casing might be off though for java.

Example 1:

```
 var elements = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//div[@id='toast-container']//*"));
```

This will give you all elements within the div with id toast-container.

Example 2:

```
 var el = driver.findElement(by.id("toast-container"));
 var elements = el.findElements(by.xpath("//*"));
```

The seconds example does the same as the first, but you create the toast-container element first so you can do whatever you want with it from that point on.

Once you have your list of elements, make a foreach loop and check the class names. So you can say:

```
foreach(WebElement element in elements)
{
    try{
         var className = element.getAttribute("class");
       }
    catch(Exception e)
       {
         //do whatever you want to do with elements which have no class in them
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to just get the `outerHTML` of the parent element.

```
 String html = driver.findElement(By.id("toast-container")).getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

That will dump all the HTML of the parent and children. From there you can get whatever you want. I'm assuming you don't just want the classes but would like to know what all elements exist and what classes are on which elements.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. OP have exclusively asked how to retrieve all nested classes, while you pointed to the outer HTML and asked OP `you can get whatever you want`.

Comment: @DebanjanB Good thing you don't revenge downvote I guess... I stated, `I'm assuming you don't just want the classes but would like to know what all elements exist and what classes are on which elements.`